# Gerrit with HTTP authentication throws up configuration error

Tags: apache, gerrit, basic-authentication

I have read a few posts on this but it does not throw light on what exactly is going wrong in my case. I have create a new configuration file called `gerrit` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and create a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. The file looks like this.

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ServerName localhost

        <Location "/r/login/">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthUserFile /home/gerrit/passwd/passwords
            Require valid-user
        </Location>

        AllowEncodedSlashes On
        ProxyPass /r/ http://localhost:8900/r/ nocanon
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have created the password file using `htpasswd -c /home/gerrit/passwd/passwords <user-name>`.

My gerrit configuration looks like this.

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
[database]
        type = mysql
        hostname = localhost
        database = reviewdb
        username = gerrit
[auth]
        type = HTTP
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
        smtpUser = example@example.com
[container]
        user = gerrit
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = proxy-http://localhost:8900/r/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

I do not exactly understand all pieces of the config file. After having restarted both gerrit and reloading config/restarting apache2 server, I try accessing `http://localhost:8900/r/`, it redirects to `http://localhost:8900/r/login/` and says

> The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization
>   header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.
>
> If the HTTP server is Apache HTTPd, check the proxy configuration
>   includes an authorization directive with the proper location, ensuring
>   it ends with '/':

Kindly point to any glaring error!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it through `http://localhost/r/` (port 80). Otherwise the Apache proxy wouldn't authenticate you.

Comment: Oh okay. Though it is not redirecting me the page. I change the config to <VirtualHost *:8901>, reloaded config, accessed     `http://localhost:8901/r/` but it refuses connection.

Comment: That's probably an Apache problem. But I'm wondering, why you don't stick to port 80 for the moment for Apache.

Comment: It gives the default page of Apache when I access port 80

Comment: You could disable the default page or use name-based virtual hosting.

Answer (score 0):

My gerrit version is **v2.16.4**. Initially,I also got the same "Configuration Error" page, but after doing the following changes.
1. vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
changed VirtualHost *:82 and add Listen 82
```

2. configure /home/gerrit2/gerrit_site/etc/gerrit.config

```
[gerrit]  
  basePath = git  
  serverId = 41b98026-b39d-4c6c-bb9e-88b89a304727  
  canonicalWebUrl = http://your-gerrit-ip:8088/  
[database]  
  type = mysql  
  hostname = yczc5  
  database = reviewdb  
  username = gerrit2  
[index]  
  type = LUCENE  
[auth]  
  type = HTTP  
[receive]  
  enableSignedPush = false  
[sendemail]  
  smtpServer = yczc5  
[container]  
  user = gerrit2  
  javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre  
[sshd]  
  listenAddress = *:29418  
[httpd]  
  listenUrl = proxy-http://*:8088/  
[cache]  
  directory = cache
```

Above error resolved, you should probably check options in ***[gerrit]*** and ***[httpd]***